# Why this anonymous function doesn't work?

Tags: r, dplyr, namespaces, tidyverse, anonymous-function

I tried this in R and it produced the outcome I expected:

```
> iris %>% mutate_at("Sepal.Length", ~ replace(., str_detect(Species, '^seto'), NA))
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2           NA         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3           NA         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4           NA         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6           NA         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7           NA         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8           NA         3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9           NA         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10           NA         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```

But this one only returns an error:

```
> iris %>% mutate_at("Sepal.Length", function(x) replace(x, str_detect(Species, 'set'), NA))
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Sepal.Length`.
i `Sepal.Length = (function (x) ...`.
x object 'Species' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I (apparently wrongly) assumed that the two syntaxes are identical, but they didn't give the same outcome. Why?

Comment: Use `.$` inside the second one  `replace(x, str_detect(.$Species, 'set'), NA)`

Comment: Also note that `mutate_at` and other scoped tidyverse verbs have been [superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html).  `across()` is now the preferred method of implementing this functionality.

Comment: They don't give the same result because of scoping rules in R.
In the second case R does not know what the object `Species` is because it is neither defined in the function environment nor in any of its parent environment (which in this case is only the global environment).
For more details I would recommend [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)

Comment: Also see [this chapter](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts) to understand what `~` does in `purrr`:

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cettt. It's very helpful :)